# Arrange concatenated dataframe in a sequence and replace NaN with some String

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Below is my code wherein I have concatenated the mismatch of two data frames in one single data frame showing it side by side. But it shows the mismatched records not according to the sequence and in an unordered manner with respect to the other data frame.

I have derived the mismatch from the two data frames raw and bob

```
#data frame 1
raw = pd.DataFrame({'EntityID': ['Appple', 'Mango','Grapes' ,'Banana'],
                    'Date': [10, 20, 30,55], 'Val': [10, 30, 15,89]})

# create data_frame2 by creating a dictionary
# in which values are stored as list
bob = pd.DataFrame({'EntityID': ['Appple','Dongo' ,'Banana', 'Mango','Rea','Hpo','Pauy'],
                    'Date': [10, 20, 30,5,9,8,98], 'Val': [100, 200, 15,21,33,44,44]})

match = raw.merge(bob, how='inner', indicator=False)

#print(match.to_string(index=False))
mismatch = (pd.concat([raw, bob], keys=["Mismatch raw", "Mismatch bob"])
                .drop_duplicates(keep=False).unstack(0)
                .swaplevel(axis=1).sort_index(axis=1, ascending=False)
           )
print(mismatch)
```

I am getting the output as follows.

```
Mismatch raw                Mismatch bob               
           Val EntityID  Date          Val EntityID  Date
0         10.0   Appple  10.0        100.0   Appple  10.0
1         30.0    Mango  20.0        200.0    Dongo  20.0
2         15.0   Grapes  30.0         15.0   Banana  30.0
3         89.0   Banana  55.0         21.0    Mango   5.0
4          NaN      NaN   NaN         33.0      Rea   9.0
5          NaN      NaN   NaN         44.0      Hpo   8.0
6          NaN      NaN   NaN         44.0     Pauy  98.0
```

My expected output should be

```
Mismatch raw                 Mismatch bob               
           Val EntityID   Date          Val EntityID  Date
0         10.0   Appple   10.0        100.0   Appple  10.0
1         30.0    Mango   20.0        200.0    Mango  20.0
2         15.0   Banana  300.0         15.0   Banana  30.0
3         89.0   Grapes   55.0         NaN     Nan    Nan
3         NaN      NaN       Nan        21.0    Dongo   5.0
4          NaN      NaN    NaN         33.0      Rea   9.0
5          NaN      NaN    NaN         44.0      Hpo   8.0
6          NaN      NaN    NaN         44.0     Pauy  98.0
```

Also instead of NaN I want some String to be written 'No record found for this entity ID'
If you see in the expected output, Apple Apple, Banana Banana, Mango Mango, etc are placed side by side which is user-friendly. In the actual output, it is jumbled up.

Is there any way I can achieve this in Pandas?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do that with an outer `merge` on `EntityID`, after duplicating the `EntityID` columns in both dataframes with a new name that matches the suffixes used in the merge. Afterwards restrict the dataframe to those rows in which at least one of the corresponding value pairs differs. E.g.:

```py
mismatch = (
    raw.assign(EntityID_raw=raw["EntityID"])
    .merge(bob.assign(EntityID_bob=bob["EntityID"]),
           on="EntityID", how="outer", suffixes=("_raw", "_bob"))
    .drop(columns="EntityID")
    .loc[lambda df: df["Date_raw"].ne(df["Date_bob"]) | df["Val_raw"].ne(df["Val_bob"])]
    .fillna("No match")
)
cols = (col.split("_") for col in mismatch.columns)
mismatch.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples((s, p) for p, s in cols)
```

Result for the sample:

```
        raw                           bob                    
       Date       Val  EntityID      Date       Val  EntityID
0      10.0      10.0    Appple      10.0     100.0    Appple
1      20.0      30.0     Mango       5.0      21.0     Mango
2      30.0      15.0    Grapes  No match  No match  No match
3      55.0      89.0    Banana      30.0      15.0    Banana
4  No match  No match  No match      20.0     200.0     Dongo
5  No match  No match  No match       9.0      33.0       Rea
6  No match  No match  No match       8.0      44.0       Hpo
7  No match  No match  No match      98.0      44.0      Pauy
```